# insert html after all selected class javascript

Tags: javascript, dom

I want to make a different change on all elements who are sharing the same class, however, i can't use queryselectorAll as insertAdjacentHTML do not support queryselectorAll. How can i do that?

```
var description = document.querySelector("h1.plp__title");

function showDescription (){
    if(description.textContent = "shoes"){
        description.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend','<p>Hello World</p>');
    }else if(cdescription.textContent = "Bags"){
        description.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend','<p>Hello World2</p>');
    } else {
        return;
    }
};
```

Comment: what exactly do you mean by *insertAdjacentHTML do not support queryselectorAll*?

Comment: `queryselectorAll` returns an array-like container of elements. You have to iterate over it and call this function for each element.

Comment: it will show TypeError: description.insertAdjacentHTML is not a function if i use queryselectorAll

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll(...).forEach(el => el.insertAdjacentHTML(....));`

Comment: You can't use Node properties against a NodeList. You're expecting jQuery functionality in vanilla JS. You can iterate the NodeList and then use insertAdjacentHTML on each Node.

Comment: `=` is assignment not comparison. Use `===` instead. Then use querySelectorAll and loop over the results .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`queryselectorAll` returns an array-like container ([`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList)) of elements. You have to iterate over it and call this function for each element.

```js
var descriptions = document.querySelectorAll("h1.plp__title");

function showDescription() {
  descriptions.forEach(description => {
    if (description.textContent === "shoes") {
      description.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', '<p>Hello World</p>');
    } else if (description.textContent === "Bags") {
      description.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', '<p>Hello World2</p>');
    } else {
      return;
    }
  });
}

showDescription();
```

```html
<h1 class="plp__title">shoes</h1>
<h1 class="plp__title">Bags</h1>
```

`description.textContent = "shoes"` and `description.textContent = "Bags"` are assignments, not comparisons.

Answer (score 1):

querySelectorAll returns a nodeList. You will have to iterate through that list, and use insertAdjacentHTML within the iteration.